# JRuby: Create Java InputStream or byte[] from RubyString

Tags: java, string, jruby

I have a Java method I want to call from JRuby.  The argument I want to pass is just a normal string (`org.jruby.RubyString`), but the Java method is overloaded to take either:

- `java.io.InputStream`
- `byte[]`
- `com.google.protobuf.ByteString`

What's an easy way I can convert my string to an instance of one of those classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it: [org.jruby.RubyString#to_java_bytes](http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/CallingJavaFromJRuby#Ruby_String_to_Java_Bytes_and_back_again).