# How to convert org.jruby.RubyString to java.io.InputStream

Tags: ruby, jruby

I am using JRuby with a Java library. The type of an input parameter of the Java method is InputStream, and I am using JRuby to call this method, how could I revert something like "/directory/item.txt" to InputStream for the Java method? Thank you.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3875884/9859). On my phone right now, but I think you'd start with `RubyString#to_java_bytes` and then pass those to something that implements the `InputStream` interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RubyString#to_java_bytes` to convert the string to bytes, then wrap it in a [`java.io.ByteArrayInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html),
which is a subclass of `java.io.InputStream`:

```
>> "an arbitrary string"
"an arbitrary string"
>> _.to_java_bytes
=> byte[97, 110, 32, 97, 114, 98, 105, 116, 114, 97, 114, 121, 32, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103]@7133da86
>> java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.new(_)
=> #<Java::JavaIo::ByteArrayInputStream:0x73e22a3d>
>> _.java_kind_of? java.io.InputStream
=> true
```

All at once:

```
inputstream = java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.new("an arbitrary string".to_java_bytes)
```